# Calculating Eulers Totient Function for very large numbers JAVA

Tags: java, optimization, cryptography, public-key-encryption, factorization

I've managed to get a version of Eulers Totient Function working, albeit one that works for smaller numbers (smaller here being smaller compared to the 1024 bit numbers I need it to calculate)

My version is here -

```
public static BigInteger eulerTotientBigInt(BigInteger calculate) { 

    BigInteger count = new BigInteger("0");
    for(BigInteger i = new BigInteger("1"); i.compareTo(calculate) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) { 
        BigInteger check = GCD(calculate,i);

        if(check.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)==0)  {//coprime
            count = count.add(BigInteger.ONE);          
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

While this works for smaller numbers, it works by iterating through every possible from 1 to the number being calculated. With large BigIntegers, this is totally unfeasible.

I've read that it's possible to divide the number on each iteration, removing the need to go through them one by one. I'm just not sure what I'm supposed to divide by what (some of the examples I've looked at are in C and use longs and a square root - as far as I know I can't calculate an accurate an accurate square root of a BigInteger. I'm also wondering that if for modular arithmetic such as this, does the function need to include an argument stating what the mod is. I'm totally unsure on that so any advice much appreciated.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

PS I deleted this question when I found [modifying Euler Totient Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709813/modifying-euler-totient-function). I adapted it to work with BigIntegers -

```
public static BigInteger etfBig(BigInteger n) {

    BigInteger result = n;
    BigInteger i;

    for(i = new BigInteger("2"); (i.multiply(i)).compareTo(n) <= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
         if((n.mod(i)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) 
         result = result.divide(i);
         while(n.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)== 0 ) 
             n = n.divide(i);
     }      
 if(n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0)
 result = result.subtract((result.divide(n)));
 return result;
}
```

And it does give an accurate result, bit when passed a 1024 bit number it runs forever (I'm still not sure if it even finished, it's been running for 20 minutes).

Comment: Oversimplifying somewhat, you must be able to factor n to compute the totient function for 1024 bit numbers. In crypto protocols that involve computing the totient function you already have the prime factorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are trying to write is equivalent to factoring the argument `n`, which means you should expect it to run forever, practically speaking until either your computer dies or you die. See this post in mathoverflow for more information: [How hard is it to compute the Euler totient function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3274/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-euler-totient-function).

If, on the other hand, you want the value of the totient for some large number for which you have the factorization, pass the argument as sequence of (prime, exponent) pairs.

Comment: You're completely right, thanks. What was throwing me was a line in our notes saying N  = 55 = 5 x 11. I was reading that to mean he had factored 55, but now that I look at your answer it's obvious he chose two co prime primes to generate N.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 10):

There is a formula for the totient function, which required the prime factorization of n.
Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

The formula is:

```
phi(n) = n * (p1 - 1) / p1 * (p2 - 1) / p2 ....
were p1, p2, etc. are all the prime divisors of n.
```

Note that you only need BigInteger, not floating point, because the division is always exact.

So now the problem is reduced to finding all prime factors, which is better than iteration.

Here is the whole solution:

```
int n;  //this is the number you want to find the totient of
int tot = n; //this will be the totient at the end of the sample
for (int p = 2; p*p <= n; p++)
{
    if (n%p==0)
    {
        tot /= p;
        tot *= (p-1);
        while ( n % p == 0 ) 
            n /= p;
    }
}
if ( n > 1 ) { // now n is the largest prime divisor
    tot /= n;
    tot *= (n-1);
}
```

Comment: Does that mean if I use n-1 for p1 (n is prime so phi n = n-1) that p2 etc will be the primes I'm looking for? Or will it return the count of the prime divisors?

Comment: What I mean to say is, how do you get p1 p2 etc, the prime divisors of n? Or are they given by computing the phi(n) you mentioned above.

Comment: While I appreciate the solution, the one you have posted was the original I was using - and there's no way I'm fitting a 1024 bit number into an int.

Comment: Euler's Theorem is more worried about the value of n, and the phi(n) So if you get products of n that are prime.  Any positive integer x should equal 1 for x^phi(n) mod n ....  phi(n)  is the two primes that produce n...like n = pg.  The phi(n) = (p-1)*(g-1).

Answer (score 0):

The etfBig method has a problem.
Euler's product formula is n*(**(factor-1)**/factor) for all factors.
Note: Petar's code has it as:

`tot /= p; 
 tot *= (p-1);`

In the etfBig method, replace `result = result.divide(i);` 
with

`result = result.multiply(i.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).divide(i);`

Testing from 2 to 200 then produces the same results as the regular algorithm.