# How to compute Euler's totient function φ in Java?

Tags: java, function, math, encryption

I'm working on making an encryption program for fun, and I'm having issues doing some of the math. I need to: "[Compute φ(n) = φ(p)φ(q) = (p − 1)(q − 1), where φ is Euler's totient function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Key_generation)" (number 3).

So I was looking at the Euler totient function link, and I couldn't figure out how to compute it. I'm doing this in Java, and something tells me there is a function I can use for φ, but i'm not sure what it is. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Everything seems to be writted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216853/calculating-eulers-totient-function-for-very-large-numbers-java

Comment: You're missing one important piece of information.  This definition relies on `p` and `q` being prime.  That gives you the base step of a recursion.  Without insisting that `p` and `q` are prime, the definition given is meaningless.

Comment: @DavidWallace You said _"This definition relies on p and q being prime"_ .No, it relies on the fact that p and q have to be relatively prime to each other, not primes themselves (they could but that's not compulsory). For example, 9 and 4 are valid for the definition (`phi(36) = phi(9)*phi(4)`).

Comment: Yes, but not for `phi(36) = (9-1)(4-1)`, which is what the definition above says.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, I think you said that because of this line _"Choose two distinct prime numbers p and q."_ and yes obviously because of the definition (and it's true since it's hard to find the two primes that produced the number `n` if you only know the product). I was speaking about the totient function itself (i.e in `φ(pq) = φ(p)φ(q)` `p` and `q` just have to be relatively primes), not its implementation in RSA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there's no Java built-in function that computes φ. However, if you look at what's being said here, you're given a direct way to compute it: φ(pq) = (p - 1)(q - 1), so computing φ(n) is equivalent to computing (p - 1)(q - 1) if you know the values of p and q.

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh sweet baby jesus, you are completely right. I honestly didnt see that 0.o

Comment: Keep in mind that the simple formula is not applicable for any two numbers (in case of valid p and q for RSA, it is ok though)

Comment: Yeah, this answer is not going to solve your problem.