# Counting numbers co-prime to n which are less than m

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

Counting numbers co-prime to n which are less than m, m

I thought of doing this by **(phi(n)/n)*m**, but it always have some small error.

One way can be using inclusion-exclusion principle, but i am looking for a better algorithm than that.

eg

```
n = 20 m = 10
{1, 3, 7, 9}
Ans = 4
```

Comment: A helpful Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019040/how-many-numbers-below-n-are-coprimes-to-n

Comment: How about sum(mu(d)*floor(m/d) for d|n)?

Comment: All of those talk about calculating phi, while i need to count coprimes which are less than m.

Comment: possible duplicate of [modifying Euler Totient Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709813/modifying-euler-totient-function)

Comment: @Nabb what is mu? can you write more clearly.

Comment: @SteveJessop I was thinking of getting a better/faster algorithm than that.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: StackOverflow doesn't really have a means for you to "nudge" an old question to get better answers. So your options are to ask a different question (perhaps specifically request the best known algorithms), or to earn more rep and put a so-called "bounty" on the old question. In this case I think making this question more specific is the way to go.

Comment: @SteveJessop sorry man thats the best i can do:P

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Regarding Nabb's comment, `mu` is the Möbius function, `µ(n) = (-1)^r` if `n` is the product of `r` distinct primes (`r` can be 0), `µ(n) = 0` if `n` is not squarefree. Regarding the answer to the other question, unless `m` is very small, the inclusion-exclusion principle is the best you can have (among the known algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

First you can find all x < m that x is prime and x is divisor of n. It is calculate in O(m * (x.count))

```
i = 1;

while x[i] not empty do  
{
    j = 1;

    while x[i] * j < m
    {
        s[(x[i] * j)] = false;
        j++; 
    }

    i++;
}
```

Now you can find all s[k] that s[k] = true.

It is calculate in O(m)

So you can do all steps in O(m * (x.count))